# Trying to understand a "Cannot convert value of type ... to expected argument type" error related to a generic enum

Tags: swift, generics

I'm running into some kind of quirk of generic programming, and would love some help with this. Apologies if this has already been asked, it's hard to put into search terms.

Given this code:

```
enum Result<T> {
    case success(T)
    case failure(Error)
}

protocol ObjectProtocol {}
class ObjectClass: ObjectProtocol {}

func describe(result: Result<ObjectProtocol>) -> String {
    return "\(result)"
}


let result = Result.success(ObjectClass())
print(describe(result: result))
```

On the last line, I get the error:

`error: cannot convert value of type 'Result<ObjectClass>' to expected argument type 'Result<ObjectProtocol>'`

What's odd is that if I replace the last two lines with this (removing the variable definition and just passing the `Result` inline), it works fine:

```
print(describe(result: Result.success(ObjectClass())))
```

Why does one work and not the other?

edit:

Making the function generic fixes the issue:

```
func describe<T: ObjectProtocol>(result: Result<T>) -> String {
    return "\(result)"
}
```

However, if the Result were being passed not to a function (which can easily be made generic) but to the case of another enum, I'm not sure how you would resolve the issue. E.G.:

```
enum Result<T> {
    case success(T)
    case failure(Error)
}

protocol ObjectProtocol {}

class ObjectClass: ObjectProtocol {}

enum RequestStatus {
    case completed(result: Result<ObjectProtocol>)
    case notMadeYet
}

let result = Result.success(ObjectClass())
let status = RequestStatus.completed(result: result)
```

This gives the same error as above.

Comment: You can make the enum generic just like you are with the function

Comment: @dan I could make the entire enum generic, yes. I chose a bad example — if the enum has many cases that may handle different things (in our app, for example, we have an enum `Screen` where different cases are different screens the user can visit, for analytics purposes), that becomes untenable, since each case that uses a protocol like this would have to have that protocol added as a generic type on the entire enum.

Comment: Another possible insight is that both protocols and templates are methods of *meta-typing* and one level of meta may be enough. That is, make it a design requirement that all uses of the enum adopt `ObjectProtocol` through `extension`s. This does not constrain the types you can use but does add bookkeeping. Then you can do away with the generic typing altogether.

Comment: @BaseZen I'm not sure exactly what you mean -- the goal is not for the enum to adopt ObjectProtocol itself, but rather to wrap something of type `ObjectProtocol`. Your idea of one level of meta being enough is interesting though! Could you expand a little more concretely on how that would look?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Great question. What you are seeing is that for simple things like assignment of arrays and other generics, Swift exhibits covariance. These work:

```
let result: Result<ObjectProtocol> = Result.success(ObjectClass())
print(describe(result: result))
// SUCCESS: you assigned to a variable

print(describe(result: Result.success(ObjectClass())))
// SUCCESS: you "assigned" to a field
```

That is, you may ASSIGN a `Result<ObjectClass>` expression to a variable of type `Result<ObjectProtocol>`.

However function arguments and parameters *are not covariant*; you cannot PASS a `Result<ObjectClass>` to a parameter of type `Result<ObjectProtocol>`. These fail:

```
let result: Result<ObjectClass> = Result.success(ObjectClass())
print(describe(result: result))
// ERROR: can't pass wrapped class to wrapped protocol

let result = Result.success(ObjectClass()) // inferred class
print(describe(result: result))
// ERROR: can't pass wrapped class to wrapped protocol
```

These things are usually taken care of by having your function not take a parameter of `Result<ObjectProtocol>` but rather "a `Result` parameterized by any class implementing `ObjectProtocol` (and making the function generic) which I just see you figured out in your edit!

[Here is an article that may be helpful](https://nomothetis.svbtle.com/type-variance-in-swift).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! This seems to describe what's going on here. I'll check out that article.

Answer (score 0):

The type-inferencing engine is amenable to influence. To get type harmony along the lines you're thinking, you can simply do:

```
let result = Result.success(ObjectClass() as ObjectProtocol)
```

so that you're taking control of what `T` means exactly. It can be surprisingly subtle.

These works equally well:

```
let foo = ObjectClass()
let result = Result.success(foo as ObjectProtocol)
```

And:

```
let foo = ObjectClass()
let result = Result<ObjectProtocol>.success(foo)
```

In other words, don't fall back on the inferencing engine too much.

Another possibility is to throw away generic types entirely:

```
protocol ObjectProtocol { /* What does this really require from an Object, anyway? */ }

class ObjectClass { /* ... */ }

/* For the module that relies on the enum, you can add the compatibility. */
extension ObjectClass: ObjectProtocol { /* Is this a marker type or adding substantial behavior? */ }
extension Array: ObjectProtocol {} /* Add any Swift built-in type with extensions */

/* Note the cleaner syntax. */
enum Result {
    case success(ObjectProtocol)
    case failure(Error)
}

enum RequestStatus {
    case completed(result: Result)
    case notMadeYet
}
let foo = ObjectClass()
let result = Result.success(foo)
/* This might be too flexible though -- depends on your design! */
let anotherResult = Result.success(Array<Int>())
let status = RequestStatus.completed(result: result)
let anotherStatus = RequestStatus.completed(result: anotherResult)
/* anotherStatus & status are of the same type. With templates you could have prevented that. */
```

Finally:

```
/* Let's give full throttle back to tye type-inferencing engine,
 allowing Generics to assume their viral propagation tendencies. */
enum Result<T> {
    case success(T)
    case failure(Error)
}

enum RequestStatus<T> {
    case completed(result: Result<T>)
    case notMadeYet
}

/* Now this code doesn't change at all, but... */
let foo = ObjectClass()
let result = Result.success(foo)

let anotherResult = Result.success(Array<Int>())
let status = RequestStatus.completed(result: result)
let anotherStatus = RequestStatus.completed(result: anotherResult)
/* ...anotherStatus & status are now incompatible types! */
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment — that was a typo on my part, I was indeed passing the class instead of an instance. In your example, you're passing Result inline. This works as expected. But if you check my (now fixed) code, you'll see that assigning the Result to a variable, and then passing the variable still fails.

Comment: Re-written entirely to account for that and to explain my one-level-of-meta suggestion.